# Laravel DB table and eloquent method updateOrCreate

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

```
    DB::table("mytable")->updateOrCreate([
      'user_id' => $user_id,
      'active' => 1,
      'created_at' => Carbon::now()
    ]);
```

But this code return me error:

> Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::updateOrCreate()

So, according to this answer [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-after-renaming-tables-call-to-undefined-method-updateorcreate) (user *stanb*) I added:

```
protected $table = 'mytable';
```

And change code:
`DB::table($this->table)->updateOrCreate([`...

But still I have this same error

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
DB::table('table name')
->updateOrInsert(
    ['email' => 'admin@admin.com', 'name' => 'Admin'],
    ['id' => '7']
);
```

I disagree with the other answer, we can use query builder to insert or update.

Comment: Thank you for giving an example where we can actually specify the table. This is the only example that would work in my case.

Answer (score 2):

It's Eloquent method, so you need to use model. Also, you need to pass two arrays as parameters:

```
Model::updateOrCreate([
  'user_id' => $user_id
],
[
  'active' => 1,
  'created_at' => Carbon::now()
]);
```

In this example, if there is a record where `user_id = $user_id`, the record will be updated.

Comment: Maybe but please see stanb response [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-after-renaming-tables-call-to-undefined-method-updateorcreate)

Comment: @michal this is not related because you're trying to use this method on query builder instance and not on an Eloquent model. Just try the code from the answer.

Comment: I know I can create a model I wanted to check another way ;) But thanks for your answer.

Comment: @michal it's impossible to use the method with `DB::table()`

Comment: You can use updateOrInsert with DB::table though. But updateOrCreate won't work.